# cannot log into server via telnet PHP

Tags: php, authentication, telnet

I'm using a [PHP Telnet Class][1] to connect to server via telnet to send commands. It connects to the server successfully but it fails to login in..

```
require_once "PHPTelnet.php";

$telnet = new PHPTelnet();

// if the first argument to Connect is blank,
// PHPTelnet will connect to the local host via 127.0.0.1

$result = $telnet->Connect('172.20.66.100','username','password');

if ($result == 0) {
   $telnet->DoCommand('another command', $result);

   echo $result;
   $telnet->Disconnect();}
```

===============================================================================
 UPDATE:
My script is working, there was some conflict going on with my virtual machine......

Comment: What is the failure message?

Comment: How can you tell it fails? When you establish a Telnet connection, no answer is given by the server.

Comment: I can check  my login activity through my log file...

Comment: 1st: do a var_dump at $result. See what Telnet is giving you. 2nd: remove the `if($result == 0)` line and see if DoCommand works.

Comment: when I do a var dumb $result it gives  int(3)

Comment: [PHP Telnet] Connect failed: Login failed
int(3)

Comment: How can you tell the problem is with PHP connection and not the server?

Comment: When I telnet to my server using command prompt everything works fine

Comment: Please can you post your telnet session?  Either your server is not returning data in the expected format, or it is not responding to the login request fast enough.  The default waiting time for logging in is 1 second.  You could try sleeping for longer perhaps (line 73)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $url = 'tcp://ADDRESS_HERE:PORT_HERE';
    $fp = stream_socket_client($url, $errno, $errstr, 10);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo ("$errstr ($errno)<br />\n");
        exit;
    } else {
        $command = 'execute_command_line' . PHP_EOL;
        fwrite($fp, $out);

        stream_set_blocking($fp, true);

        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $output = stream_get_contents($fp);
        }

        fclose($fp);
        echo output;
    }
```

Comment: where do I place the username and password?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation in the PHPTelnet website you have the parameters to the constructor in the wrong order.

In the library's documentation there is the following example:

```
$result = $telnet->Connect('www.somewhere.com','login name','password');
```

Therefore, you should have:

```
$result = $telnet->Connect('172.20.66.100','username','password');
```

Source: [PHPTelnet Documentation](http://www.geckotribe.com/php-telnet/#usage)

**EDIT**

You mentioned that you get erro nº 3. In the source code, error 3 has the following description: *Connect failed: Login Failed*

Which points to the following URL:
[Information about Error 3](http://www.geckotribe.com/php-telnet/errors/login.php)

Which lists the possible causes as:

- You misspelled your username or password (i.e. Your credentials are wrong)
- Telnet service is not available for your username and password (i.e. Your user does not have permissions to access the Telnet service)

Comment: That was a typo, when I  pasted my code I changed my actual username and password back to "password" "username" my bad sorry about that.. My script is still not working

Comment: You mentioned that you get erro nº 3. In the source code, error 3 has the following description: Connect failed: Login Failed

Which points to the following URL:
http://www.geckotribe.com/php-telnet/errors/login.php

Which lists the possible causes as:
- You misspelled your username or password (i.e. Your credentials are wrong)
- Telnet service is not available for your username and password (i.e. Your user does not have permissions to access the Telnet service)

Comment: I know but everything is correct , I telnet to the server from command prompt with the same credentials and everything works fine...

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in the library. Maybe you can try this one instead: https://github.com/ngharo/Random-PHP-Classes/blob/master/Telnet.class.php

Comment: I tried that library but it also seems to have a bug, when I created an object $telnet = new Telnet(); I got a fatal error, so I searched  and found an updated version of the library http://sobek.su/Projects/php/telnet.class.php 
I'll update my post with my new code..